# Try to get Facebook Data from user

Tags: facebook, http, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

i try to get facebook data from User with http.get but it not works!

here my code

```
  firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result){

      let token = result.credential.accessToken;
      let user = result.user;

      let userDetails = this.http.get("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token="+token).
      map(result => result.json);
```

and the error is "Cannot read property 'http' of undefined "

Comment: that´s not related to facebook, "this" is undefined. also, http.get is not synchronous: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback

Comment: thanks! it works now :)

Comment: you are welcome. please either delete your question or answer and accept it ;)